# how to make check box selection for Listbox in mvc4 Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, listbox

i have a listbox selection in my view ,i need to hold the ctrl key for select multiple items , i am using the following code :

```
    @Html.ListBoxFor(
     m => m.SelectedSkills ,
     new MultiSelectList( listItems, "Id", "Name", @Model.SelectedSkills ),
     new { Multiple = "multiple" }
    )
```

i want to put a checkbox infront of each list item,user can check/uncheck the checkbox to select/deselect an item ,and when it post the form,only the selected checkboxes values should be passed in controller action , How can i acheive this...

Comment: That is not a normal html control. There might be plugins which does that.

Comment: You can do it like [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/786243/ASP-NET-MVC-CheckBoxList-Basic-Implementation).

Comment: thanks  @Ali Soltani ,thats is the solution for which i am exactly looking for,thanks again...

Comment: I added the solution to the answer, so if someone had a similar question, it would be easier to find solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

**First method: Create html tag**

```
<ul>
    @foreach (var g in Model.AllSkills)
    {
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox"
               name="SelectedSkills"
               value="@g.ID" id="@g.ID"
               @{if (condition)
               {><text> checked='checked' </text>  } } />
        <label for="@g.ID">@g.Name</label>
    </li>
    }
</ul>
```

Now you can post the form and see the selected value is stored in model.SelectedSkills field.

**Second method: Using MvcCheckBoxList**

```
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.CheckBoxListFor(model=>model.SelectedSkills,
    model=>model.AllSkills,
    x=>x.ID,
    x=>x.Names)
</div>
```

For more information please see [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/786243/ASP-NET-MVC-CheckBoxList-Basic-Implementation).